# Table not rendering properly with Mustache.js and Boostrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, mustache

I'm trying to use Mustache.js but while my table is being created is not applying the Boostrap class properly. Only the header gets the css.  I tried applying the class with jquery after the button click but did not help. I also try embedding the template inside the table but id did not work.

I have this html.

```
  <table id="mTable" class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th>FY</th>
    <th>COST</th> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

then my template

```
<script id="priceTemplate" type="text/template">

  <tr>
    <td>{{FY}}</td>
        <td>{{COST}}</td>

  </tr>
  </script>
```

my Ajax code.

```
    $('#cmdSubmit').on('click', function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            var PriceTemplate = $('#priceTemplate').html();
            $priceTable = $('#mTable');
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "mywebservice.asmx/GetData",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                datatype: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    var pricedata = eval(msg.d);
                    $.each(pricedata, function (i, price) {
                        $priceTable.append(Mustache.render(PriceTemplate, price));

                    });

                }

            });

        });
```

my table is showing data but is looks like the template is not getting stylized by bootstrap. 
[image]

TIA,

Comment: You're missing `thead` and `tbody`.

Comment: OK. you lead me to answer. I added a <tbody></tbody> then from jquery, $('#mTable >tbody').append(Mustache.render(PriceTemplate, price));